# Import indexes with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have two tables that have identical constraints, datatypes and primary keys is there a way to 'import' the index from one table to another if they're on the same server, but in separate databases?

Comment: 99% sure you need to script indexes out then run the scripts on the new table.

Comment: @JNK: add another 1%. One might configure replication between the two databases and set the first one to send DDL changes to the second, but it's not really a nice solution :-). You could use a db compare tool to have the script generated for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option will be to script out the index and create it on the new table in the other database.